# How to make a graphical representaiton of this continuous signal x(-1.5t+1)

Tags: signal-processing

So let's suppose this is the $x(t)$ signal:

[image]

This is what  i know

- $x(t+1)$ should be shifted by 1 on $y$ axis , so the signal will start from $-1$ and end to $1$ instead of $0$ to $2$
- $x(-t)$ will reflect the signal
- $x(1.5t)$ will suppress the signal by $1.5$

How can i correctly calculate and make a graphical representation of $x(-1.5t+1)$ ?

**Note:** I'm new with with this kind of mathematics and expressions , any edit would be appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the graph, then you can use the following sequence:
$$x(t) \xrightarrow{\text{suppress}} x(1.5t) \xrightarrow{\text{reflect}}x(-1.5t) \xrightarrow{\text{shift by} \frac{2}{3}}x(-1.5t+1).$$

If you want algebraically then, you first need to find $x(t)$ from the graph. From the graph given,
$$x(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } t \leq 0 \text{ or } t \geq 2\\
1 & \text{ if } 0 <t \leq 1\\
2-t & \text{ if } 1 < t <2.
\end{cases}$$
Now you can compute the composite function $x(-1.5t+1)$.

Comment: Thank you !! is there any particular reason why we follow the sequence you mentioned and not in another way?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis We could have approached as follows as well:$$x(t) \xrightarrow{\text{reflect}} x(-t) \xrightarrow{\text{suppress}}x(-1.5t) \xrightarrow{\text{shift}}x(-1.5t+1).$$

Comment: Just make sure when you draw the graph that $x(-1.5t+1)$'s graph is *not* obtained by shifting $x(-1.5t)$'s graph left by $1$ unit. Since $x(-1.5t+1) = x\left(-1.5\left(t - \frac{1}{1.5}\right)\right)$, we actually have that $x(-1.5t+1)$'s graph is obtained by shifting $x(-1.5t)$'s graph *right by $\frac{1}{1.5} =\frac{2}{3}$ units*.

Comment: Oh now i get it! thank you!